# Compress multiple files individually with Gzip

Tags: linux, unix, compression, gzip

I have several directories that look like this:

```
dir1/
  |_foo.txt
  |_bar.txt
dir2/
  |_qux.txt
  |_bar.txt
```

For each of this directory I want to compress the files inside it into *.gz format
then delete the uncompressed ones. So finally we hope to get something like this:

```
 dir1/
   |_foo.gz
   |_bar.gz
 dir2/
   |_qux.gz
   |_bar.gz
```

Is there a simple Unix way to do it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
gzip */*.txt
```

But the extension for each file will be .txt.gz, as gzip uses it to know the original filename.

Comment: Just for clarification as it is not obvious: gzip will delete the uncompressed files itself.

Comment: is there a way to not delete the originals?  I currently am using the -c flag (gzip -9 -c style.css > style.css.gz)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258972/gzip-multiple-files-individually-and-keep-the-original-files

Comment: -k to --keep :)

Answer (score 13):

gzip -r dir1 dir2

Answer (score 10):

The following will work even if you have sub-directories. E.g. dir1/dir2/.../foo.txt

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec gzip {} \;
```

Comment: You could also do `gzip ./**/*.txt`, which recurses into all directories within the current one, gzipping all text files, and deleting the originals.