# Gzip multiple files individually and keep the original files

Tags: linux, compression, gzip

I am looking to gzip multiple files (into multiple .gz files) in a directory while keeping the originals.

I can do individual files using these commands:

```
find . -type f -name "*cache.html" -exec gzip {} \;
```

or

```
gzip *cache.html
```

but neither preserves the original.  I tried

```
 find . -type f -name "*cache.html" -exec gzip -c {} > {}.gz
```

but that only made a {}.gz file.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `>` in the last command gets parsed by the same shell which runs `find`. Use a nested shell:

```
find . -type f -name "*cache.html" -exec sh -c "gzip < {} > {}.gz" \;
```

Answer (score 10):

I'd use `bash(1)`'s simple `for` construct for this:

```
for f in *cache.html ; do gzip -c "$f" > "$f.gz" ; done
```

If I knew the filenames were 'sane', I'd leave off the `""` around the arguments, because I'm lazy. And my filenames are usually sane. But scripts don't have that luxury.

Answer (score 7):

**`-k, --keep` (gzip 1.6)**

gzip 1.6 (June 2013) added the `-k, --keep` option, so now you can:

```
find . -type f -name "*cache.html" -exec gzip -k {} \;
gzip -k *cache.html
```

or for all files recursively simply:

```
gzip -kr .
```

Found at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46786/how-to-tell-gzip-to-keep-original-file

Answer (score 0):

Since you have multiple files, GNU Parallel might be useful:

```
find . -type f -name "*cache.html" | parallel gzip '<{} >{}.gz'
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1